# delete iOS local record based on server result

Tags: ios, rest, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are developing notification systems to notify the front end to modify local records based on interactions with server. Create and update are fine but delete is embarrassingly not straightforward.

Currently we introduce a deleted field in the server response and then front end will pretend it’s deleted.

But I’m wondering is there anyway to notify the front end to actually delete a record?

EDIT: What's the common way to do this? Actually delete or mark as delete in front end?

Comment: Are you sending the ‘to be deleted records’ (id of record) in the push notification payload??

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not? Pass the index id of the record you want to delete locally in your push notification. Then call your delete custom method.

You can create a custom method say

```
deleteMethod :(NSString *) indexRecord
{
     //Handle your local database deletion here
}
```